# Bookdown: why is final document title becoming the project title?

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown

I'm building the book via `bookdown` at https://github.com/proback/BeyondMLR.

For some reason, the title of the final chapter becomes the title of the document overall. Thus, the title of the document built from that repo isn't "Beyond Multiple Linear Regression" but instead "Chapter 11: Multilevel Generalized Linear Models."

Where does `bookdown` pull the title from?

Here's the content of `_bookdown.yml`:

```
book_filename: "bookdown-BeyondMLR"
chapter_name: "Chapter "
output_dir: docs
rmd_files: ["index.Rmd", 
  "01-Introduction.Rmd",
  "02-Beyond-Most-Least-Squares.Rmd",
  "03-Distribution-Theory.Rmd",
  "04-Poisson-Regression.Rmd",
  "05-Generalized-Linear-Models.Rmd",
  "06-Logistic-Regression.Rmd",
  "07-Correlated-Data.Rmd",
  "08-Introduction-to-Multilevel-Models.Rmd",
  "09-Two-Level-Longitudinal-Data.Rmd",
  "10-Multilevel-Data-With-More-Than-Two-Levels.Rmd",
  # "11-Generalized-Linear-Multilevel-Models.Rmd",
  "99-References.Rmd"]
clean: [packages.bib, bookdown.bbl]
```

EDIT: Commenter suggested that there could be stuff in index.Rmd. [Here is the original](https://github.com/proback/BeyondMLR/blob/master/index.Rmd), which isn't mine, so I don't want to post the whole.  I've put some of my best guesses as to parts of index.Rmd that might be affecting below.

I should also note that the problem seems to also occur when the output is HTML.

````
--- 
title: "Beyond Multiple Linear Regression"
subtitle: "Applied Generalized Linear Models and Multilevel Models in R"
author: "Paul Roback and Julie Legler"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%B %d, %Y')`"
documentclass: krantz
bibliography: ["bib/articles.bib", "bib/books.bib", "bib/misc.bib"]
link-citations: yes
colorlinks: yes
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
description: "An applied textbook on generalized linear models and multilevel models for advanced undergraduates, featuring many real, unique data sets.  It is intended to be accessible to undergraduate students who have successfully completed a regression course.  Even though there is no mathematical prerequisite, we still introduce fairly sophisticated topics such as likelihood theory, zero-inflated Poisson, and parametric bootstrapping in an intuitive and applied manner. We believe strongly in case studies featuring real data and real research questions; thus, most of the data in the textbook arises from collaborative research conducted by the authors and their students, or from student projects. Our goal is that, after working through this material, students will develop an expanded toolkit and a greater appreciation for the wider world of data and statistical modeling."
github-repo: proback/BeyondMLR
graphics: yes
cover-image: "data/book_cover.jpg"
---


```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
library(sessioninfo)

options(
  htmltools.dir.version = FALSE, formatR.indent = 2, 
  width = 55, digits = 4
)
```

# Preface {-}

```{block, include=is_html_output(), purl=FALSE}
Welcome!  This is the [online version](https://bookdown.org/roback/bookdown-BeyondMLR/) of *Beyond Multiple Linear Regression: Applied Generalized Linear Models and Multilevel Models in R*.  Hard copies can be purchased through [CRC Press](https://www.routledge.com/Beyond-Multiple-Linear-Regression-Applied-Generalized-Linear-Models-And/Roback-Legler/p/book/9781439885383) or on [Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/Generalized-Correlated-Methods-Chapman-Statistical/dp/1439885389).  
```
````

Comment: Sometime some configurations are also in the `index.Rmd` such as title and document settings. check there and see if that same appears there.

Comment: So since it's not my index.Rmd, I'm a little hesitant to post the total here, but I'll include a link to the original, as well as paste some of the file to my question above.

Comment: it might be behaving like this, because Rmarkdown handles `#` very specifically, what is the result when you uncomment the final chapter?

Comment: If I comment out the final chapter (Chap 11), the title of Chap 10 becomes the overall title. Uncommenting Chap 11 reverts the previous behavior (Chap 11 title becomes overall title).

Comment: The file name is supposed to be come from this line:

book_filename: "bookdown-BeyondMLR"


The Title inside the document is supposed to come from this line:

title: "Beyond Multiple Linear Regression"


Please post the first few lines of chapters 10 and 11.

Comment: Chapter 10:


```
---
title: "Chapter 10"
subtitle: "Multilevel Data with More Than Two Levels"
output:
  html_document: default
  pdf_document:
    number_sections: yes
---

# Multilevel Data With More Than Two Levels {#ch-3level}
```

Chapter 11:

```
---
title: "Chapter 11"
subtitle: "Multilevel Generalized Linear Models"
output:
  pdf_document:
    number_sections: yes
  html_document: default
editor_options: 
  chunk_output_type: console
---

# Multilevel Generalized Linear Models {#ch-GLMM}
```